# What would be the best way to queue mysql queries? In terms of speed

Tags: php, mysql, redis, message-queue, gearman

When a user submits a form on my site, I have to do a job based on the form which is essentially:

- Check for user locks (in redis, prevents user from doing naughty things), if no locks continue and put job queue lock in place, otherwise quit job and give error to user
- Update row/s in a mysql table, potentially delete some rows in the same table and do at least 1 insert (potentially across different tables)
- remove job queue lock

I would like to queue these jobs up as they come in, with the queue always processing new jobs that get put into it.

I am using php and mysql. I have looked at gearman and also resque for php. Gearman seems like it might be overkill. And also I want to potentially be able to handle thousands of these jobs per second. So speed is important.

It's crucial that these jobs in the queue occur sequentially and in the order they come in. It would also be a bonus if every half a second I could insert a job to the front of the queue (it's a different job but kind of related).

I've never done anything like this before.

Comment: This is more a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already into PHP & Redis it looks like [Resque](https://github.com/mjphaynes/php-resque) may work for you.